# There is only one layout page that you need to customize and do not match multiple at the same time

Tags: reactjs

It's like I'm trying right now and doing that, for example, the front page, which is my app.jsx, which is being sent via Router.jsx and so on to Content.jsx. Content must contain Narbar, Footer and Meta as title and description. So I only have to work with design somewhere instead of being located in several places.

[Image here to show what i try.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0ZNB.png)

The problem is just that I want to send the title and description with the over to the content.jsx file that make App.jsx only content content and description and what should be on each page.

Router.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

//home site here
import Home from './Home/App';

//Nyheder
import Nyheder from './Nyheder/index';
import Nyhed from './Nyheder/nyhed';

//Account
import Login from './Account/Login';
import Forget from './Account/Forget';
import Create from './Account/Create';

//Team site
import Team from './Team/index';

//Error
import Error404 from './404/error404';

const Router = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/Account/Login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/Account/Forget" component={Forget}/>
            <Route path="/Account/Create" component={Create}/>
            <Route path="/Team/:Url" component={Team}/>
            <Route path="/Raadgivning/:Url" component={Team}/>
            <Route path="/Nyheder" component={Nyheder}/>
            <Route path="/Nyhed/:Url/:Id" component={Nyhed}/>
            <Route component={Error404} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Router;
```

Content.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DocumentMeta from 'react-document-meta';

//DESIGN
import Header from '../component/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../component/Footer/Footer';
import Section from '../component/Header/Section';

import Router from '../component/Router';

export default class content extends Component {
  render(...props) {
    return (
        <DocumentMeta {...props.meta}>
            <Header />
            <Section title={props.meta.title} />


            <Router/>


            <Footer />
        </DocumentMeta>
    );
  }
}
```

App.jsx (Home site)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//view helper
import CreateUser from '../Helper/_viewHelper/createUsers';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const meta = {
            title: 'Forside',
            description: 'I am a description, and I can create multiple tags',
          };
        return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="container">
        <h2>Toppen here</h2>
        </div>
        <CreateUser/>
        <div className="container">
        hej
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet ?